# How would one convert this static logging method to log to a form control?

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have the following very basic static class:

```
public static class Log {
    public static void WriteLine(object line) {
        Console.WriteLine("[" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt") + "]: " + line);      
    }
}
```

I created this so it would be easier to transition to an alternative logging method for release. I now want to convert this method to output its lines to a ListView on a form. The problem though is that I cannot think of an elegant way to link this output from this method to that form control (and form in general really).

In addition, this method is called on many different threads, so it needs to be thread safe. Any suggestions?

**EDIT 1:**

So I tried to implement an event to allow for this, which gets me closer, but not quite there yet:

```
public static class Log {
    public delegate void LogDelegate(object text);

    public static event LogDelegate OnWriteLine;

    public static void WriteLine(object line) {
        Console.WriteLine("[" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt") + "]: " + line);
        if (OnWriteLine != null) {
            OnWriteLine.Invoke(line);
        }
    }
}
```

And in my form:

```
    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // hook into the log so we can see output on form
        Log.OnWriteLine += LogToForm;
    }

    private void LogToForm(object line) {  
        listView_Log.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(
            (string)line
        ));      
    }
```

This issue I have with this now is that I get an InvalidOperationException: "Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'listView_Log' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.".

I suppose this makes sense, but I am unsure how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the correct way to proceed. If this class method is called from different thread probably it is better to provide a delegate that will be called whenever there is a new log message. The interested partners could set the code to be called in their own context

Comment: Ahh I see. So you think I should create an event that my form can register to, and then fire it whenever the method is called? This is a good idea.

Comment: You can also implement the observer pattern, then you will be able to inform many subscribers of what happens. And by the way, you will store logs in order they came in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because accessing UI controls from non-UI thread is forbidden.

```
private void LogToForm(object line) {
    listView_Log.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        listView_Log.Items.Add(new ListViewItem((string)line));
    });
}
```

Use Control.Invoke to tackle the cross-thread problem.